# How to get reference to current model in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have very simple scenario. I retrieve particular instance of a model

```
model: function(params) {
  return this.store.findRecord('project', params.id);
},
```

and I provide form for editing it:

```
<h2>Edit project {{model.title}}</h2>
<label>Project title</label> 
<br/>
{{input value=model.title size="50"}}

<label>Project description</label>
{{input value=model.description size="50"}}

<label>Project explanation</label>
{{textarea value=model.full_description cols="50" rows="6"}}

{{#bs-button action="saveProject"}}Save{{/bs-button}}
```

Then in `saveProject` action handler I need to have a reference to model that was edited. How can I retrieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not pass the model to `bs-button`? That way you can send the record with the action

Comment: I've tried, but I don't know how to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add the `bs-button` component's js and hbs file?

Comment: No exactly understand what you mean. I didn't wrote this component, it's from there http://kaliber5.github.io/ember-bootstrap/

Comment: I don't understand, Can't you access `this.get('model')` from within the action?

Comment: Can you provide your current version of the `saveProject` action and also indicate where you've put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [api docs](http://kaliber5.github.io/ember-bootstrap/api/classes/Components.Button.html) for the `bs-button` component you can see that the value property is sent along with the action, in your case you would just need to set `value=model`:

`{{#bs-button action="saveProject" value=model}}Save{{/bs-button}}`

And your `saveProject` action would look like:

```
saveProject: function(record) {
  // Handle the saving here
}
```

Comment: Don't get it. You're going to pass the model to the component, so it can just pass it back to you again?

Comment: @torazaburo So it can send it with the action

Comment: But we already knew what the model was. That's how we were able to send it to the component in the first place. What am I missing?

Comment: @torazaburo I don't pass model into component it provided through model hook defined on route and I didn't know how to get reference to the same model

Comment: @NikitaLuparev I was referring to this proposed solution, your code. He is passing the model to the component as `value=model`, and my point was that although that would work, it doesn't make that sense, because what's the point in passing the model to the component only so it can pass it back to us?

Comment: @torazaburo based on the info that the OP has given I can't assume that he is handling the action in the current route/controller, while you can access it via `this.get('model')` this won't be true if the action is from a child route and the action is handled on a parent route.

Answer (score 1):

Reference the model property on the controller:

```
// controller.js
actions: {
  saveProject() {
    this.get('model') . save(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: This assumes that you are handling the save action in the controller.

Comment: Indeed, which IMHO is the correct place to be handling it.